# React Native: Undefined symbol: _swift_stdlib_isStackAllocationSafe in Xcode

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I am getting an error after updating Xcode to `13.3.1` in react native. Before upgrading `Xcode` app was working fine. Also, I haven't changed anything in code. But still I am getting error. I don't why after updating I am getting this error.

```
Error: Undefined symbol: _swift_stdlib_isStackAllocationSafe


Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_swift_stdlib_isStackAllocationSafe", referenced from:
      function signature specialization <Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed> of generic specialization <Swift.String, Swift._NativeSet<Swift.String>> of Swift._NativeSet.genericIntersection<A where A == A1.Element, A1: Swift.Sequence>(A1) -> Swift._NativeSet<A> in libLaunchDarkly.a(FlagChangeNotifier.o)
      function signature specialization <Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed> of generic specialization <Swift.String> of Swift._NativeSet.intersection(Swift._NativeSet<A>) -> Swift._NativeSet<A> in libLaunchDarkly.a(FlagChangeNotifier.o)
      function signature specialization <Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed, Arg[2] = Owned To Guaranteed> of function signature specialization <Arg[0] = [Closure Propagated : generic specialization <LaunchDarkly.FeatureFlag> of closure #1 (Swift.String) -> Swift.Bool in (extension in LaunchDarkly):Swift.Dictionary< where A == Swift.String>.symmetricDifference(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>) -> Swift.Array<Swift.String>, Argument Types : [[Swift.String : LaunchDarkly.FeatureFlag][Swift.String : Any]]> of generic specialization <Swift.String> of Swift._NativeSet.filter((A) throws -> Swift.Bool) throws -> Swift._NativeSet<A> in libLaunchDarkly.a(FlagChangeNotifier.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

`react-native": "0.64.2"`

Why I am getting this error? And, how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Now go to [Xcode Releases page](https://xcodereleases.com/) or [Apple Developer More Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) and download an older version of Xcode, as needed and install. You need an Apple ID to login to that portal.

After install, you can also switch between multiple versions:

Xcode > Settings > Locations > Command Line Tools

[select older version and run project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq3bA.png)

Note: I'm still trying to solve the problem, because after compiling and installing with low version, the file I uploaded to my phone with TestFlight did not work. However, there were those who solved the problem in older versions in this way.

Answer (score -1):

Have you yet figured this one out? I suspect the Launch Darkly RN SDK is way out of date, as they're still using the older state management form.